# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_default_manager' when running lettuce with django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, lettuce

I am trying to use lettuce to implement BDD for creating an rest framework api but when I execute the command `python manage.py harvest` I get following error

```
/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 818, in get_related_field
    'queryset': related_model._default_manager,
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_default_manager'
```

Detailed stack trace is:

```
(envSamplePayApp)root@ubuntu:/pythonWorkspace/samplePayProject# python manage.py harvest
Django's builtin server is running at 0.0.0.0:8000
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/pythonWorkspace/samplePayProject/envSamplePayApp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lettuce/django/management/commands/harvest.py", line 167, in handle
    result = runner.run()
  File "/pythonWorkspace/samplePayProject/envSamplePayApp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lettuce/__init__.py", line 137, in run
    self.loader.find_and_load_step_definitions()
  File "/pythonWorkspace/samplePayProject/envSamplePayApp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lettuce/fs.py", line 49, in find_and_load_step_definitions
    module = __import__(to_load)
  File "/pythonWorkspace/samplePayProject/envSamplePayApp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/tests/test_serializer_import.py", line 4, in <module>
    from rest_framework.tests.accounts.serializers import AccountSerializer
  File "/pythonWorkspace/samplePayProject/envSamplePayApp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/tests/accounts/serializers.py", line 6, in <module>
    class AccountSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  File "/pythonWorkspace/samplePayProject/envSamplePayApp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/tests/accounts/serializers.py", line 8, in AccountSerializer
    admins = UserSerializer(many=True)
  File "/pythonWorkspace/samplePayProject/envSamplePayApp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 196, in __init__
    self.fields = self.get_fields()
  File "/pythonWorkspace/samplePayProject/envSamplePayApp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 232, in get_fields
    default_fields = self.get_default_fields()
  File "/pythonWorkspace/samplePayProject/envSamplePayApp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 716, in get_default_fields
    field = self.get_related_field(model_field, related_model, to_many)
  File "/pythonWorkspace/samplePayProject/envSamplePayApp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

All the code can be found at [downloadcode](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1Jr9mOzPkxESTEyM3laZTRJNWs/edit?usp=sharing).

Note when I run the api from browser it works fine.

What is causing the `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_default_manager'`?

Comment: Can you include your code inline?

Comment: for some reason `related_model` is `None` when you try to access its `_default_manager` attribute. we can't say more without your code

Comment: I have posted the link with entire code. is there code from any specific file i should add inline?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this error just now.  The cause of my error was due to the fact that I had created a `ManyToManyField` from Model X of App A to Model Y of App B.  When I tried to create schema migration via `python manage.py schemamigration --auto app_a`, it raised this error because I had yet to:

1. include `'app_b'` in the `INSTALLED_APPS` tuple of `settings.py`
2. not having created the initial schema migration for `app_b` (which would not be possible with adding `app_b` to `INSTALLED_APPS`).

Effectively, I linked to an model that was not known at the time. Hopefully this can help someone in the future.

EDIT: Actually, on further inspection, I realize now **the reason that this error is being raised so ambiguously is because of [django-debug-toolbar](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar)**.  Apparently DjangoDebugToolbar is causing some issues around errors propagating properly.  Disabling it in `INSTALLED_APPS` allowed the errors to become apparent.